# Which Virtual-memory translation technique (consider x86) is used generally?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, x86, paging, memory-segmentation

It is known that there are different kinds of Virtual-address translations (x86) with the help of MMU such as Segmentation, Paging, Combined Segmentation-Paging (Paged segmentation,  Segmented Paging), etc. Each having its own advantages and disadvantages.

My Questions:
1) Are general Operating systems like Linux/Windows use only one particular technique (like Paging)?
2) If 2 or more techniques are available for a given OS, when & where each one will be used?
Can we customize according to our needs?
3) If 'Paging' only is used, then x86's segment registers are used in what ways?

Comment: What is your programming question? Are you trying to decide what model to use for the operating system you are writing?

Comment: Not to decide on a model. My question is how each model is utilized in a given OS?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

In general, modern operating systems on x86 use paging and not segmentation.  This means the base address of segment registers is set to zero and the segment limit is set to the maximum.  Paging is used to map virtual addresses to physical addresses, this gives the OS fine grained control of the address space of a process, protection between processes, and protection between privileged (kernel) and user address space.  Segments are still used in x86 for special purposes:

- to run legacy operating systems and applications in a virtual environment
- to efficiently access [thread local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) for each thread in a multithreaded application (with thanks to @PaulA.Clayton for pointing this out).

Microsoft Windows switched from segmentation to a `flat, linear` memory model with Windows 95.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751120.aspx

> Windows 95 addresses this issue by using the 32-bit capabilities of the 80386 (and above) processor architecture to support a flat, linear memory model for 32-bit operating system functionality and Win32-based applications. A linear addressing model simplifies the development process for application vendors, and removes the performance penalties imposed by the segmented memory architecture.

In order to run old Win16 applications (Windows 3.1) Windows 95 ran a 16-bit virtual machine where all Win16 applications ran.  Newer, 32-bit applications ran in separate address spaces using the paging facility of the MMU.

Here's the relevant description from the link above

[image]

Comment: FS and GS can be used to provide base pointers (e.g., for thread local storage or [OS-level] processor-specific storage). These are allowed to have a non-zero base in x86-64 while other segments must have a zero base.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - Very good point... I'll take the liberty of updating my answer with your information, thank you.